# match_parent with max_width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an ImageView and I want to set something like this:
`min_with=match_parent and max_width=value` 
does someone know how to do that?

Comment: It would be helpdul to have some context on what you hope to achieve, perhaps a diagram (it doesn't need to be fancy). It's a ad confusing since match_parent is generally the largest that view can be and still be visible (barring clipChildren shenanigans) so setting that as the lower of two values is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your parent is not the root parent and your parent width is not match_parent either.

You can set your parent width as wrap_content and set child width as wrap_content but set child min width to some dp so your child won’t have less width than min width but it will hug the parent on all sides.

You can also take advantage of linear view and its weightSum, weight to childrens

We can go in details if you share more data and small drawing of what you want to do.

Comment: I was looking for a view to match with the parent in small screens and limit it on large screens, maybe a custom view is better. Yes, my parent is not the root parent and the parent view is not match_parent also my view may not fill view port because of small size.